# Coarse moduli space and rational points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, moduli-space

Let $K$ be a field (not necessarily algraically closed). Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a contravariant functor from the category of schemes over $K$ to sets and $M$ be a coase moduli space for the functor. So, there is a morphism of contravariant functors from $\mathcal{F}$ to $h_M$ where $h_M:=Hom(-,M)$ such that $\mathcal{F}(\bar{K})$ is bijective to $h_M(\bar{K})$. So, the natural morphism from $\mathrm{Spec}(\bar{K})$ to $\mbox{Spec}(K)$ gives rise to a natural transformation. As far as I understand  this means that if $\mathcal{F}(K)$ is non-empty which maps to something non-empty in $\mathcal{F}(\bar{K})$ the image of $\mathcal{F}(K)$ in $h_M(\bar{K})$ is non-empty (due to the bijectivity over $\bar{K}$). By the commutativity of the diagram (coming from the natural transformation) this means that $h_M(K)$ is non-empty. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Even without assuming $M$ is a coarse moduli space, the existence of a natural transformation $\mathcal{F}\to h_M$ gives rise to a set function $\mathcal{F}(\mathop{\text{Spec}}K)\to h_M(\mathop{\text{Spec}} K)$. In particular, if the domain of this function is non-empty, then so is the co-domain.

Comment: Why? Does it follow from some property of functors? Do you have a reference in mind?

Comment: It's part of the definition of natural transformation. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation

Comment: @Dussek: Could you please be a bit more specific. I tried the link. As far as I understand an object on the domain goes to an object in the target. But the target contains the empty set as an object. So, why can it not map it to that?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. From wikipedia: "The natural transformation must associate to every object $X$ in $C$ a morphism $\eta_X : F(X) \to G(X)$ between objects of $D$." In your case, $X = \mathop{\text{Spec} K}$ is an object of $C = \text{Schemes}_{/K}$, so the natural transformation $\mathcal{F}\to h_M$ must give rise to a morphism $\eta_{\mathop{\text{Spec} K}}: \mathcal{F}(\mathop{\text{Spec} K})\to h_M(\mathop{\text{Spec} K})$ of objects in $D = \mathrm{Sets}$.